# I was trying to solve below problem on python i get exectly output but still they are show me error

Tags: python, python-3.x

[here is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktIgH.jpg)

[error shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlK2n.jpg)

[My code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F76Na.jpg)

here is my code

```
    class Person:
    apples = 0
    ideas = 0

johanna = Person()
johanna.apples = 1
johanna.ideas = 1

martin = Person()
martin.apples = 2
martin.ideas = 1

def exchange_apples(you, me):
  #"you" and "me" will exchange ALL our apples with one another
you.apples,me.apples=martin.apples,johanna.apples
  return you.apples, me.apples

 def exchange_ideas(you, me):
  #"you" and "me" will share our ideas with one another

  you.ideas = martin.ideas+johanna.ideas
  me.ideas =you.ideas
  return you.ideas, me.ideas

exchange_apples(johanna, martin)
print("Johanna has {} apples and Martin has {} apples".format(johanna.apples, martin.apples))
exchange_ideas(johanna, martin)
print("Johanna has {} ideas and Martin has {} ideas".format(johanna.ideas, martin.ideas))
```

I exchange the value as they said but still i got error as shown in image 2

Comment: Please put your question and error in the post. And your code is formatted incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting error because you are not solving the question correctly, in this case you are not correctly exchanging apples and ideas as described in the given question,

here is the correct code,

```
class Person:
    apples = 0
    ideas = 0

johanna = Person()
johanna.apples = 1
johanna.ideas = 1

martin = Person()
martin.apples = 2
martin.ideas = 1

def exchange_apples(you, me):
  #"you" and "me" will exchange ALL our apples with one another
    temp = you.apples
    you.apples = me.apples
    me.apples = temp

    return you.apples, me.apples

def exchange_ideas(you, me):
    #"you" and "me" will share our ideas with one another
    temp = you.ideas
    you.ideas += me.ideas
    me.ideas += temp

    return you.ideas, me.ideas

exchange_apples(johanna, martin)

print("Johanna has {} apples and Martin has {} apples".format(johanna.apples, martin.apples))

exchange_ideas(johanna, martin)

print("Johanna has {} ideas and Martin has {} ideas".format(johanna.ideas, martin.ideas))
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person:
    apples = 0
    ideas = 0

johanna = Person()
johanna.apples = 1
johanna.ideas = 1

martin = Person()
martin.apples = 2
martin.ideas = 1

def exchange_apples(you, me):
    #Here, despite G.B. Shaw's quote, our characters have started with       #different amounts of apples so we can better observe the results. 
    #We're going to have Martin and Johanna exchange ALL their apples with #one another.
    #Hint: how would you switch values of variables, 
    #so that "you" and "me" will exchange ALL their apples with one another?
    #Do you need a temporary variable to store one of the values?
    #You may need more than one line of code to do that, which is OK. 
    you.apples,me.apples=me.apples,you.apples
    return you.apples, me.apples

    
def exchange_ideas(you, me):
    #"you" and "me" will share our ideas with one another.
    #What operations need to be performed, so that each object receives
    #the shared number of ideas?
    #Hint: how would you assign the total number of ideas to 
    #each idea attribute? Do you need a temporary variable to store 
    #the sum of ideas, or can you find another way? 
    #Use as many lines of code as you need here.
    temporary=you.ideas+me.ideas
    you.ideas =temporary
    me.ideas =temporary
    return you.ideas, me.ideas

exchange_apples(johanna, martin)
print("Johanna has {} apples and Martin has {} apples".format(johanna.apples, martin.apples))
exchange_ideas(johanna, martin)
print("Johanna has {} ideas and Martin has {} ideas".format(johanna.ideas, martin.ideas))
```